# Select entire row on group by aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm having some struggle with something that should be a simple SQL query.

This is my initial database schema:

[image: ![initial database schema]

Also prepared the example in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/43a9ef/2)

The query I've ended up with is:

```sql
select
       b.ad_id,
       b.auction_id,
       max(b.amount) as max,
       max(b.created_at) created_at
from bid b
where b.user_id = '601'
group by b.ad_id, b.auction_id
```

But in the result, I need the whole row from the `bid` table:

```sql
select
       b.id,
       b.ad_id,
       b.auction_id,
       max(b.amount) as max,
       max(b.created_at) created_at
from bid b
where b.user_id = '601'
group by b.ad_id, b.auction_id
```

Which fails with: `[42803] ERROR: column "b.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 16`. Cannot add the `id` field in the GROUP BY clause, because it will add some extra rows I don't need.

What I need is to select from the `bid` table the highest record (amount field) grouped by auction_id and ad_id.

I think I need to make some self inner join or subselect but right now I'm not able to write the SQL.

Comment: Please describe the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Updated with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need is to select from the bid table the highest record (amount field) grouped by auction_id and ad_id

Take a look at [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in the docs. Your desired result would be obtained by the following query.

```
select DISTINCT ON (b.ad_id, b.auction_id)
       b.id,
       b.ad_id,
       b.auction_id,
       b.amount
       b.created_at
from bid b
where b.user_id = '601'
ORDER BY b.ad_id, b.auction_id, b.amount DESC
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. Please let me check. Gave you +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent row for each auction for the given user, then you can use a correlated subquery to filter:

```
select b.*
from bid b
where b.user_id = '601' and
      b.created_at = (select max(b2.created_at)
                      from bid b2
                      where b2.auction_id = b.auction_id and
                            b2.user_id = b.user_id
                     );
```

This seems like a sensible interpretation of what you want.  I don't know if `ad_id` is needed.